# Entity Framework Change Assembly Model not recognised

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an MVC 5 website with using the entity framework V6.1.1. The entity framework DbContext classes and models were originally all inside the website project. This project had 3 DbContext classes and 3 databases. I had also enabled migrations and applied one one of these databases.

I have now moved all the entity framework classes including the models and the migrations to a separate project and since then I have been getting the following error for the databases where a migration has been applied:

> The model backing the 'MyContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created.

The database has not changed. I have also made sure the Context Key is the same in both the Configuration constructor and the database __MigrationHistory table.

I have also been seeing the following behavior:

- I do a Get-Migrations in the package manager console and the correct migrations are returned. Then I am able to build and run the site and no error message is shown until I next make a change and build the solution.
- If I change the Context Key in either the database of the Configuration constructor there is no error, but I assume that the migrations are not all being picked up.

I have also been looking through all the migrations files including the designer files and the namespaces all match up. If anyone could shed some light on this problem it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to add a new migration, even if it's empty? I've found in the past that this step solved the inconsistencies between the model and the migrations.

Comment: Yes I have also tried that, it works up until I have to build the site again and then I am back to the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this in the constructor of 'MyContext'

```
> Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(null);
```

Comment: This should remove the error, but it's not exactly a solution. The underlying problem will still exist. Also, this shouldn't be in the context's constructor. It should only be executed once, so maybe in a static constructor of the context or in the app start.

Comment: Yes this does remove the error, but now I have no initializer which I suppose isn't too much of a problem.  Would you mind explaining how it fixes it and why it isn't a full solution?  Thanks

Comment: OK I realise that this just skips the code where the error is being thrown. Thanks for the suggestion but I am going to try and get to the root of the problem.